# How can I use 'timeofday' data type in a Google Charts Histogram?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a histogram using Google's `timeofday` data type, but keep getting the error "Invalid Row Index NaN. Should be in the range [0-0]." when the chart loads. If I use `number` as the data type and change the arrays to integers it works, but that won't let me format as HH:MM:SS. Something tells me that `timeofday` might not be supported for a histogram, but I can't find anything in the docs to support that. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);    

function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = {
      cols: [
        {
          type: 'timeofday',
          label: 'Clock-in'
        }
      ],
      rows: [
        { c: [{v: [8, 15, 0]}] },
        { c: [{v: [8, 30, 0]}] },
        { c: [{v: [8, 45, 0]}] }
      ]
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
      title: 'Clock-in times',
      legend: { position: 'none' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that you only have 1 column. You need at least 1 more data column to represent the number of occurrences  of each time. Anything more complicated than that would require me to see all of the code. A working plunk, fiddle, or pen would also be helpful.

Comment: @Balrog30 In the google visualizations Histogram type, you only need one column. (It calculates the # of occurrences for you.) As I said above, if I change the arrays to numbers and change the type to 'number' then it works perfectly.

Comment: Just for the record, @acsmith registered [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2025) with the google-visualization team.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Google histogram implementation ([issue #2025](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2025)).

In the meantime, the only way to get a histogram of `timeofday` values will be to put things into bins on the server side and render a bar chart.